# find first and last occurence of the matched string in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Want to insert opening and closing element for set of `<p>` tags.

input

```
<p>Para1</p>
<p>Para2</p>
<p>Para3</p>
```

expected output

```
 <div>
   <para>Para1</para>
   <para>Para2</para>
   <para>Para3</para>
 </div>
```

How to find the first and last occurrence of `<p>(.[^\<]*)<\/p>` and insert `<div>`

Comment: Please don't use regular expressions for this job. They are the wrong tool to use. Seriously. They're not very good at 'handling' tagged languages like XML and HTML. See: [Parsing (X)HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Use a parser. If this is HTML, use a HTML parser. If it's XML, an XML parser.  (there's some commonality, XML is stricter)

Comment: Agreed, the OP is explaining what he wants to do, but not why he wants to do it. We need this info first to be able to give proper advice.

Answer (score -1):

Just span your regexp from the very first `<p>` to the very last `</p>` and put the `<div>`s around it: `s#(<p>.*</p>)#<div>\n$1\n</div>#s`.

edit: as @mbethke has noticed, to be able to let `.` span accross newlines, you must use the [s-modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#s).

Comment: Don't forget the /s modifier to the regexp if your input contains newlines.
Another idea: why do this by hand at all? Modules like `Mojo::DOM` exist that make this really easy and fairly safe. Simple hand-crafted regexps are usually brittle and only a good idea if you know your inputs well and speed is very important.

Comment: I have tried to identify the first `<p></p>` set by making variable into 1 like `$i=1; $i = $i+1; if $i=1` then its first. But I can't find the last set. Is there any idea to find in this way?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean; my regexp will span across the complete set of `<p>`aragraphs in one single attempt.